# Interpretation or meaning of the following lines of code in Pine Coding

Tags: pine-script

order {{strategy.order.action}} @ {{strategy.order.contracts}} filled on {{ticker}}. New strategy position is {{strategy.position_size}}

I need help with the meaning of this line of code, the programmer who had coded for me is not in touch with me. I want to understand what this means? The goal of this line of code is to be read by the API bridge software as soon as the alert is got, and the API bridge sends a signal to broker.

Answer (score 0):

This a text for the Message field of the Alert creation dialogue. If you create a strategy alert and put this text into the message field, when the alert triggers, the variables inside of the {{}} will be replaced with values from the alert (ticker where the alert was set, position size at the time of the alert's firing, etc.).

You can learn more about these placeholders in the Help Center: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000531021